# Dictionaries suggest 透 (tou) is pictophonetic where 秀 (xiu) provides the sound. Is this through a classical chinese pronunciation?

Tags: etymology

I have several resources and dictionaries that suggest the word 透 (tou) is pictophonetic where 辶 (chuo) suggests the meaning and 秀（xiu) provides the sound. This confuses me because 透 and 秀 do not seem to be related in sound. I assumed that this may be due to a classical chinese pronunciation but was unable to verify that or find more information.

What is the correct etymology here? thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're uncomfortable with the initial t- vs. xi-? Because 透 and 秀 rhyme perfectly.

Comment: @droooze Yes, I guess that threw me off. Is the rhyme the link?

Comment: The initial is what lacks a good amount of evidence. We only know that they're barely compatible (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_consonant) vs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolo-palatal_consonant). I don't personally find the Old Chinese reconstructions convincing...

Answer (score 1):

Pronoucing them in Cantonese will make sense to you.

[透](https://ykyi.net/dict/index.php?char=%E9%80%8F)，tau3
[秀](https://ykyi.net/dict/index.php?char=%E7%A7%80)，sau3

Comment: Yes, seems that Cantonese keeps lots of ancient Chinese words(both in pronouciation and meaning)